# Install4j 7.0.5 runtime in Maven repository

Tags: install4j

I'm upgrading to Install4j 7.0.5.

In the Maven repository (https://maven.ej-technologies.com/repository/com/install4j/install4j-runtime/) there is no corresponding runtime, only 7.0.5-PRE versions. Is it planned to release it or should we used one of the 7.0.5-PRE version or the 7.0.4 version?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about that, it's fixed now.